# Form scrolls but scrollbar doesn't move

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, scrollbar

I've been developing an app for a while now that has a textbox with a vertical scrollbar. It's worked perfectly up until today. Today, after making some changes unrelated to scrolling, I noticed that the scrollbar wasn't moving up and down when I drag it with the mouse. The textbox that owns the scrollbar scrolls just fine, but the scrollbar doesn't move till I release the mouse button!

This is extremely annoying, and confusing for users of my application. My question is this: what would cause such a thing to happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the scrollbar not moving was my use of this overridden property:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams 
{ 
  get 
  { // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams; cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; 
    return cp; 
  } 
}
```

I was using it to ensure double-buffering on all controls, but it had unintended side effects.